# How do I web scrape Worldometer charts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Our organization is using Worldometers for COVID-19 data. I'm able to scrape the page state data, but our leaders want the 7-day moving average for new cases and deaths. To do this manually, you have to click on the 7-day moving average button and hover over today's date. Is there an automated method or module that is available to the public?

Link I can web scrape: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/

Data I need in the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to pull that out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if "Highcharts.chart('graph-cases-daily'" in str(script):
        jsonStr = str(script)
        data = re.search(r"(name: '7-day moving average')[\s\S\W\w]*(data:[\s\S\W\w]*\d\])", jsonStr, re.IGNORECASE)
        data = data.group(2).split('data:')[-1].strip().replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
```

**Output:**

```
print(data[-1])
148755
```

Better yet, we can pull out the dates too and make a dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import ast

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if "Highcharts.chart('graph-cases-daily'" in str(script):
        jsonStr = str(script)
        
        dates = re.search(r'(xAxis: {[\s\S\W\w]*)(categories: )(\[[\w\W\s\W]*\"\])', jsonStr)
        dates = dates.group(3).replace('[','').replace(']','')
        dates = ast.literal_eval(dates)
        dates = [ x for x in dates]
        
        data = re.search(r"(name: '7-day moving average')[\s\S\W\w]*(data:[\s\S\W\w]*\d\])", jsonStr, re.IGNORECASE)
        data = data.group(2).split('data:')[-1].strip().replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
        
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates, '7 Day Moving Average':data})
```

And to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.iloc[1:]['7 Day Moving Average'].astype(int).plot(x ='Date', y='7 Day Moving Average', kind = 'line')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To get each state, we grabbed the href for each of them then pulled out the data. I went ahead and combined all the tables and you can just query the `'State'` column for a specific state:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import ast





url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

states_list = []
rows = soup.find('table', {'id':'usa_table_countries_today'}).find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    if row.find_all('td'):
        tds = row.find_all('td')
        for data in tds:
            if data.find('a', {'class':'mt_a'}):           
                href = data.find('a', {'class':'mt_a'})['href']
                states_list.append(href)

states_list = [x for x in states_list]

df_dict = {}
for state in states_list:
    print(state)
    df_dict[state] = []
    state_url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/' + state
    response = requests.get(state_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    for script in scripts:
        for graph_type in ['cases','deaths']:
            if "Highcharts.chart('graph-%s-daily'" %graph_type in str(script):
                jsonStr = str(script)
                
                dates = re.search(r'(xAxis: {[\s\S\W\w]*)(categories: )(\[[\w\W\s\W]*\"\])', jsonStr)
                dates = dates.group(3).replace('[','').replace(']','')
                dates = ast.literal_eval(dates)
                dates = [ x for x in dates]
                
                data = re.search(r"(name: '7-day moving average')[\s\S\W\w]*(data:[\s\S\W\w]*\d\])", jsonStr, re.IGNORECASE)
                data = data.group(2).split('data:')[-1].strip().replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
            
     
                df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates, '7 Day Moving Average - %s' %graph_type.title():data}) 
                df_dict[state].append(df)
            

# Combine the tables
df_list = []
for state, tables in df_dict.items():
    dfs = [df.set_index('Date') for df in tables]
    temp_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)
    temp_df['State'] = state.split('/')[-2]
    df_list.append(temp_df)

        
results = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

Comment: I'm utterly grateful for your guidance and your response. Thank you. But what if I wanted the 7-day moving average for each state? Would the 'url' change to each state to get the latest number? Does that make sense?

Comment: @LuisVera, I added how to make a dataframe with the dates there too in case you hadnt seen yet.

Comment: I’ll have to look into where each state is stored. Most likely can grab that as well. I’ll take a look at that tomorrow morning and get back to you if that’s ok.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the 7 day moving average for each state?

Comment: Yes, my apologies for not clarifying. Ideally, I'm trying to create a dataframe that has: state, 7-day moving average of daily new cases, 7-day moving average of daily new deaths.

Comment: @LuisVera, give me a little time and I'll update this within the hour.

Comment: @LuisVera, its updated below in the `**Update:**` part. I combined all the states into 1 table. It ends up being a big table of 27000+ rows, but I guess you can play around with the code to do whatever you need to from here.

Comment: This is amazing. I'm eternally grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just scrape the page using BeautifulSoup. I got the area I want - finding the 7-day average - but I'm having difficulties trying to organize the data into a data frame. Ultimately, I just want the latest date, but I'm unsure about how to get there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/usa/california/#graph-cases-daily"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
```